# I often can't type anything suddenly in IntellijIDEA

Tags: ubuntu, intellij-idea, intellij-14, ubuntu-15.04

> os:ubuntu 15.04
>   jdk:1.8
>   idea version:idea-IU-141.1532.4

I haven't still found the regular anyway. It always burst in on me, and I can't type anything in the edit area, but it can select the code yet. And I always restart it and it were back to normal...and ... Maybe after a few minutes it come back again.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this should be a question for IntelliJ support team

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-78860

Comment: The question would be **how to update** the ibus version running on your system. Can you please look up which version you are running? Here is the shell command: `ibus version`.

Comment: Here is the release of [ibus v.1.15.11](https://github.com/ibus/ibus/releases/tag/1.5.11).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Weird keyboard locks in IntelliJ IDEA (delete & arrow keys, etc.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10430467/weird-keyboard-locks-in-intellij-idea-delete-arrow-keys-etc)