# arrow keys,backspace,delete and option not working in phpstorm

Tags: phpstorm

This problem has had me stumped all day and I still haven't figured out a solution. If I use the <kbd>delete</kbd> or <kbd>backspace</kbd> keys nothing happens but I can still enter in text just can't delete anything. I've also found that the arrow keys are scrolling instead of moving the caret and I can't format the code which is <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>.

What I have tried

- Uninstalled and reinstalled Phpstorm
- updated jdk
- invalidated cache and restart
- restarted computer
- looked through settings for an issue with key maps

So far none have worked and I have no idea what is causing it, it was working fine when I logged off my computer last night. It seems to only be effecting the code editor because if you're in the settings screen or any popup all the keys work as expected and other programs are not having the issue either

I'm running Phpstorm 9.0.1 on OSX Yosemite and have been using the bundled jdk version but at the moment is using the system jdk as I installed the other one to see if it would work.

Has anyone come across this issue before I have been searching google all day and haven't found anything so i'm hoping someone has had the same issue

Comment: Id suggest creating a support ticket, attaching your idea.log (https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206827517-Locating-IDE-log-files) to it

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue. This is annoying! Ever solve it?

Comment: Yes but not sure how I spent the whole day trying to fix it gave up shutdown the computer next day it opened fine so i'm still stumped but haven't had the issue since

Answer (score 5):

Although answers at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10430467/weird-keyboard-locks-in-intellij-idea-delete-arrow-keys-etc) are related to IntelliJ IDEA but you can try them for phpstorm.

In my case, changing keymap fixed the issue. I had imported and selected a keymap from AppCode which broke the phpStorm and WebStorm.

Comment: just happened to me as well during KDE installation: wrong keymap was applied so that I wasn't able to use Backspace

Answer (score 1):

Got this on Rider 2022.3 EAP1. Think PHPStorm, IntelliJ and PyCharm work about the same

I used Visual Studio before, so on Rider install I select VS2022 keybindings plugin.

After few days control keys just stopped work, and I found that **Settings/Keymap** is empty.
[This is 100% broken keymap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDJ6k.png)

I just select other, preferably default keymap - and there we are - all begin to work again
[That's how good keybinging look - many keys at right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gacts.png)

Answer (score 0):

Got this problem, the solution was slightly different, although related to Keymap settings as well.

Some keymap templates, mostly those based on other IDEs, are not built-in the IDE but come from bundled plugins. You need that plugin enabled to initialize your keymap, of course, but even if you duplicate / update / rename it later, **you still need to keep the plugin enabled** because your custom keymap will stay in a category related to the keymap it's based upon.

[image]

PhpStorm (or other Jetbrains IDEs I suppose) will not warn you that you have to change your keymap if you disable the plugin, and even worse, it sometimes fail to switch to another built-in keymap when you do. You're stuck with a broken custom keymap, with the exact effects OP described.