# Keyboard locks Win10 IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard, windows-10

- Using: Windows 10
- IntelliJ version: 15(.0.3)

Problem:

I currently have issues that several keys suddenly are 'locked' or something. Keys a-z, 0-9 and some others. Keycombinations like CTRL+F... etc., DELETE, BACKSPACE keep working. The keys are locked everywhere in Windows. And the combinations can still be used everywhere.

When happens this:

This happens when I work in IntelliJ and it always happend when I double pressed a String for selecting it, but not the first time (random). So maybe this is a key setting in Windows or something.

Temporary solution:

Reboot. :(

I already saw the following post: [Weird keyboard locks in IntelliJ IDEA (delete & arrow keys, etc.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10430467/weird-keyboard-locks-in-intellij-idea-delete-arrow-keys-etc#comment19898666_11302284)

This is an older post and there is assumed that I need to uncheck the Vim Emulator. I don't have this plug-in.

**Edit: Current solution**

Re-installed IntelliJ.

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered this exact same issue and the the removal of the VIM plugin (didn't have a VIM emulator) fixed it, under intellij 2016.2.4 on windows 10.
Open settings -> Plugins -> search for VIM -> remove