# IntelliJ not allowing certain keypresses

Tags: intellij-idea

I loaded IntelliJ for the first time in awhile, and noticed that many keys aren't responding in the editor.

I can type all letters, numbers, and symbols, but backspace, delete, enter and all key combinations do nothing.

This problem effects everything. I tried loading up different projects, Java, Clojure and Kotlin files; everything. It doesn't seem to be linked to a plugin (I don't even have the Vim plugin, which is the typical culprit). The only place the keys work is inside the Settings. If I type into the search box, everything's fine.

Researching, I found posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10430467/weird-keyboard-locks-in-intellij-idea-delete-arrow-keys-etc), but nothing suggested there worked.

I tried uninstalling IntelliJ (2018.3) altogether, and downloaded and installed a fresh copy (2019.2.1). Unfortunately, it still doesn't work.

Luckily, I don't need this IDE right now, but when I go back to Clojure I will. I'll note though, I am using PyCharm (2019.1.3) at the moment, and it's fine.

---

When starting IntelliJ, I get this exception in `idea.log`:

```
2019-09-01 12:22:27,754 [  14541]   INFO - il.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl - Index com.intellij.util.indexing.VfsAwareMapReduceIndex@103383af already registered for the name 'FormClassIndex' 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Index com.intellij.util.indexing.VfsAwareMapReduceIndex@103383af already registered for the name 'FormClassIndex'
    at com.intellij.util.indexing.IndexConfiguration.registerIndex(IndexConfiguration.java:80)
    at com.intellij.util.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl.initIndexStorage(FileBasedIndexImpl.java:397)
    at com.intellij.util.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl.registerIndexer(FileBasedIndexImpl.java:359)
    at com.intellij.util.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl.access$5500(FileBasedIndexImpl.java:99)
    at com.intellij.util.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl$FileIndexDataInitialization.lambda$initAssociatedDataForExtensions$0(FileBasedIndexImpl.java:2386)
    at com.intellij.util.indexing.IndexInfrastructure$DataInitialization.executeNestedInitializationTask(IndexInfrastructure.java:217)
    at com.intellij.util.indexing.IndexInfrastructure$DataInitialization.runParallelNestedInitializationTasks(IndexInfrastructure.java:205)
    at com.intellij.util.indexing.IndexInfrastructure$DataInitialization.call(IndexInfrastructure.java:166)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor.doRun(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:207)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor.access$100(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:29)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor$1.lambda$run$0(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:185)
    at com.intellij.util.ConcurrencyUtil.runUnderThreadName(ConcurrencyUtil.java:208)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor$1.run(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:181)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Not sure if it's relevant though.

Comment: Have you checked `idea.log` ? Nothing abnormal ?

Comment: @ArnaudClaudel There's a ton. I'm not sure what I'm looking for though. There are exceptions, but none seem like they're related to key listening or anything similar.

Comment: If I try to type a key that doesn't work, that alone doesn't generate an error in the log. I only get a entry that the project was saved.

Comment: After looking at similar questions, it seems that there's like several dozens of different solutions to fix it. It'll be hard to answer directly to your question. You should try them all or ask directly to JB

Comment: @Carcigenicate please [contact support](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/requests/new) with the logs attached (Help | Compress Logs and Show in ...). See if deleting [IDE folders](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544519) to start with the defaults helps. Could be some plug-in issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up nuking IntelliJ from my system entirely.

Before, I uninstalled IntelliJ, but left the caches and settings intact. This time, I had it do a full uninstall of everything, then manually went through and deleted a few lingering files that I found.

After reinstalling from complete scratch, I can type properly again.