# Arrow keys, delete and double click are not working in IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, jetbrains-ide

I have IDEA Ultimate 2019.2.4 and MacOS Catalina 10.15.4 (anyway, this bug was already present many versions of IDEA and MacOS before)

The case is:

1) I search some text in project (`cmd + shift + f`) or in file (`cmd + f`) or try to search and replace (`cmd + shift + r` / `cmd + r`)

2) I type some text in search window (i.e. 'abc xy')

3) Then I try to move cursor to the left with arrow key `<-` to delete symbol `c` - it's not working. Cursor doesn't move and just nothing happens

4) I'm setting the cursor to desired position with mouse and then try to delete symbol `c` with `delete` button - nothing happens again

5) I'm trying to select 'abc' entirely with mouse double click - and it's also not working

What IS working: cursor manual positioning with mouse single click and symbol deletion with 'backspace' key

Solution described here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10430467/weird-keyboard-locks-in-intellij-idea-delete-arrow-keys-etc](http://Solution%20described%20here) is 8 years old and doesn't work for me

Comment: Plenty of solutions are provided in that post: restarting IBus daemon, disabling Vim Emulator (IdeaVim plugin), maven clean, reverting keymap settings to default, updating all plugins, restoring IDE settings to default, switching the Boot SDK to something else, unplugging the USB keyboard. Have you tried them all?

Comment: I'd also recommend disabling all non-bundled plugins to see if any of them is interfering. Look for any errors in the _idea.log_ file (Help | Show Log in Finder) that may hint at that.

Comment: If none of the above helps, please add a comment to [IDEA-92408](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-92408) with issue description, your IDE/OS specs and _idea.log_.

Comment: check the keymap selected in **Preferences | Keymap** - such issues can occur if the chosen customized keymap extends a keymap that is missing in the installation (has to be installed as a plugin)

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause - it was just the bug of third-party JSON Formatter plugin - I uninstalled it and now everything works now

[image]